# J-1 visa and two-years home residency requirement

Tags: usa, j-visa

I was in the USA with a J-1 visa and I left the country after 4 months. How can I  check online to see I am subject to two-years home residency?

Answer (score 2):

The US Department of State Bureau of Consular Affairs gives guidance on how to seek an advisory opinion, should you be unclear of your obligation.

> If you do not know whether the two-year home-country physical presence requirement applies to you, after having reviewed the [Eligibility Information webpage](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student/residency-waiver/eligibility.html), you can request that the Department of State, [Waiver Review Division conducts an Advisory Opinion](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/glossary.html#advisory_opinion). An Advisory Opinion is a review of your exchange visitor program documents to determine if you are subject to this requirement.